# Can you summon yourself?

Tags: spells, magic, summoning, anima-beyond-fantasy

Assume two characters, a summoner and a wizard.  (The wizard is, in theory, not necessary, but let us assume them anyway.)

The wizard has learned the Path of Creation spell Chimera (Creation 80).

Said wizard then casts that spell upon the summoner, turning them into a Gnosis 25 Being Between Worlds, granting them DP, et cetera.

Due to being a Being Between Worlds, the summoner *is* summonable.

Can the summoner use their summoning abilities upon themself (and if so, what would happen if they did?)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible.

Banishment typically sends a creature to its home plane, or whatever it considers 'home'. 
Control wouldnt actually do anything, and nor would summon, aside from eating a huge pile of Zeon.

Bind on the other hand... Would definitely work. It would however trap the summoner for exactly one day. Since their essence is frozen, upkeep would result in them being ejected.